# Sample vector at random in matrix null space efficiently

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Given positive-semidefinite matrix H what is an efficient way to find vector (any vector) in H null space?

I know I can do SVD of H, then eigenvectors corresponding to small eigenvalues will define null space. But SVD is expensive and I want just one vector in H null space, generated at random.

Comment: Note that you need to solve the "linear equation system" $Ax=b$ with $b=0$.